# How to disable screenshot in android and ios in nativescript angular

Tags: android, ios, angular, nativescript, angular-nativescript

I am making an app in which students can give their test online and i would like to restrict them from taking screenshots or record screen on both iOS and android. So far i have come across android [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539997/how-disable-screenshots-in-nativescript-mobile-application#:%7E:text=getWindow().,FLAG_SECURE%2C%20LayoutParams.). I want to figure out how to do it in both android and iOS.

Comment: I disabled screenshot and screen recording in android using this code. Still confused on how to achieve in iOS                                   ` 
      if (app.android) {
        const window = app.android.startActivity.getWindow();
        window.setFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                     android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
      }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Preventing screenshots on `Android` you can use below code.

```
if (app.android) { 
const window = app.android.startActivity.getWindow();
window.setFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
 android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}
```

However, **I want to know how to prevent screenshot on iOS**, Could anyone please provide more details.

Comment: Yeh i did the same thing in my comment above. I asked this question on Apple developers forum as well and I received a reply that it's not possible [link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666812)